# Using "CryptoJS" library in a Titanium mobile project to decrypt a text message [Triple DES]

Tags: javascript, cryptography, titanium, tripledes

I have an encrypted text message and I want to decrypt it using "crypto-js" library posted on the link: http://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/

I want to decrypt using TRIPLE DES.
I downloaded the library and placed "tripledes.js" under "lib" folder in my project.
And I'm calling the function to decrypt in this way:

```
var lib_decrypt = require('tripledes');
var message = lib_decrypt.DES.decrypt(Ti.Utils.base64decode(thetext), "secretphrase");
alert(message);
```

I'm always getting this error: "Cannot call method 'decrypt' of undefined".

I checked up "tripledes.js" code and sincerely its a big library so i didn't find a solution for how to use this library to decrypt my text in Titanium.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was occured because I missed to export "CryptoJS" in "tripledes.js".
So when I put "exports.CryptoJS = CryptoJS;" in "tripledes.js", everything works fine because all tripledes library functions are related to the instance of "CryptoJS"

Comment: Hi. I am trying to do the same with AES. Did you have to require any other files from the CryptoJS library?

Comment: I can't get AES working either with this solution. Did you figure it out @LeonardoAmigoni

Comment: No, unfortunately I haven't gotten back to it yet.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the error is your object have you tried to create an instance or an object of "tripledes"

```
 var decode = require('tripledes');
 var test = new decode();
 var message = test.DES.decrypt(Ti.Utils.base64decode(thetext), "secretphrase");
```

also have you checked that tripledes.js is in order with the CommonJS Modules in Titanium?
https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides/CommonJS+Modules+in+Titanium

Comment: Dear @Mayito, no its not a problem of instantiating. The problem was occured because I missed to put "exports.CryptoJS = CryptoJS;" in "tripledes.js". Anyway thank you very much for your help because your link is very helpful